# OneNote Graph API doesn't return new pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I have a question regarding OneNote Graph API. I am using Graph API to fetch a list of notebooks, sections and pages. When I add a new notebook or section (via OneNote app or via OneNote Web) I see these changes immediately when making a new API call.

However it's not the case with the pages. Newly added pages do not appear immediately in new API calls. I see the new notebooks, new sections, but not pages created within these sections.

I didn't make exact calculations, but new pages are included in the API call responses only after some time (few hours or even days).

Is it a Onenote way of syncing data or am I missing something in the API calls?

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem :(

Comment: were you able to resolve?

Comment: @AndroidGecko, no. Still waiting for the reply. Pages appear after some period of time and that period is completely random. Tried to modify pages after immediate creation and it didn't work. Very strange API I would say :)